# Graphic card title

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed the graphic card 'GTX TITAN X' and its driver from the website of NVIDIA.

and checked my graphic card name using the command 'nvidia-smi -L'

However, the printed output is follow.

GPU 0: Graphics Device (UUID: GPU-146fb7ad-3409-4e9e-28e5-69639bd6c3d0)

but, i checked the specification of the graphic card using the command 'sysinfo', and confirm the specification of that graphic card.

and I tried to experiment using CUDA and GPU, and its successed.

Is there any problem in checking the Graphic card name?

Answer (score 1):

You easily can check it this way ...

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output will be something like this :

[image]

Another way to check it is ...

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lshw -numeric -C display
```

The output will be something like this :

[image]

Comment: thanks for comment, but i tried to type it. and results is as follow:   0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 17c2 (rev a1)
 Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1132
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Answer (score 0):

as you have an nvidia card you can run this command. `nvidia-smi` it should be installed along with your Nvidia Drivers

```
nvidia-smi
```

Output of the command is something like:

```
neil@ASUS:~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Nov 11 23:53:09 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.93     Driver Version: 340.93         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 260     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   42C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    306MiB /   895MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
neil@ASUS:~$
```

You may need update your PCI ID database with:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Here are more commands i know to find Hardware devices that you can try.

[Discover](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/discover.1.html)

to install discover run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install discover
```

to run discover

Run this is terminal

```
sudo discover | grep <Your GPU manufacturer>
```

The output of this command may look like:

```
neil@Linux-Lap:~$ sudo discover | grep NVIDIA
[sudo] password for neil: 
NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8200M G] 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode) 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode) 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode) 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller 
neil@Linux-Lap:~$
```

hwinfo

```
sudo apt-get install hwinfo
```

terminal command:

```
sudo hwinfo | grep Model | grep <Your GPU manufacturer>
```

The output may look like this.

```
neil@Linux-Lap:~$ sudo hwinfo | grep Model | grep nVidia
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller"
  Model: "nVidia ISA bridge"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE"
  Model: "nVidia MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode)"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge"
  Model: "nVidia MCP77 Ethernet"
  Model: "nVidia MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge"
  Model: "nVidia C77 [GeForce 8200M G]"
```

if `sudo hwinfo | grep Model | grep <Your GPU manufacturer>` shows nothing just type sudo hwinfo in terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for your Your GPU manufacturer

Comment: and i also tried to this command, but the output is different, The outputed Name is just 'Graphics Device'

Comment: @AndrewYu edited my answer for more thing you can try.